# How can I adjust the imported 3d body in Altium designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, footprint, 3d

I've downloaded and imported the following SMPS transformer 3d model into Altium designer but it doesn't fit my footprint how can I adjust it by changing scales and moving pins?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can import it into a 3D mechanical CAD program, and, if it imports without serious errors, edit the part. It’s better to have a Parasolid or Sldprt file but step files can work.

Comment: First check most carefully that your footprint is actually right.... You do discover dud models (obviously) but I would be checking really carefully (Like put it aside for a week then get an actual bobbin and measure). This is trying to warn you of something....

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  can you do this in a minute for me? I have no experience working with 3D modeling software. just moving pins a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imported models cannot be scaled. And also subsets (bobbin, pins, core etc.) cannot be edited individually because Altium treats the whole model as a single object. What you can do is only transformation (move and rotate).

You should import scaled and adjusted models.